# Connecting Web App to Azure SQL DB in Vnet

Tags: azure

My Web app is placed inside a Vnet as Vnet1 and subnet as Subnet1.  I wanted to use Azure Sql Server V12 as a DB.

Q1: How Azure Sql Server V12 DB will be placed  inside a Vnet & Subnet?

Q2: If Azure Sql Server V12  DB is placed inside a Vnet & Subnet then how this 
    Vnet & Subnet  will be connected to Vnet1 & Subnet1(of Web app)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I answered, assuming you were talking about SQL Database service. If assumption this is incorrect (and instead you're using SQL Server in a VM), please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign a SQL Database instance to a VNet - SQL Database is DB-as-a-Service - you access it by its `<yourdb>.database.windows.net` endpoint name.

Comment: If Azure SQL DB is not placed inside the same VNet with Azure WebApp then how connection will be established between Webapp & Azure SQL DB?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. You just... open a connection to the database endpoint. You just need to allow your Web App to access your SQL Database (an option in your database instance's firewall). This is all clearly documented. **EDIT** If you're actually working with SQL in a Virtual Machine, then please clarify, as my answer was specifically about SQL Database Service.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are referring to [service endpoints](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-sql-database-vnet-service-endpoints-now-in-public-preview/). You can configure this via the Firewall Settings for your database server instance. There you can specify a VNet access rule. In the rule, you define the Resource Group, VNet, and subnet. It will also setup the service endpoint in that subnet if one does not already exist.

Note that you can only manage FW settings on the SQL server, not the individual databases.